# Why nested loop works for one time

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am a newbie on programming, I have a problem with nested loops. I'm trying to match id from sqlite sample with nested for loops, "Match albums with artist" I know there is probably a lot of cool ways to do this but I wander why my way did not work.

```
import sqlite3
co=sqlite3.connect("chinook.db")
album=co.execute("select*from albums")
artist=co.execute("select*from artists")
albumQuery=0
artistQuery=0
for row in album:
    albumQuery+=1
    for x in artist:
        artistQuery+=1
        if(x[0]==row[2]):
            print(row[1]+" "+x[1])

print("Album Query:",albumQuery,"Artist Query",artistQuery)
```

Output:

> For Those About To Rock We Salute You AC/DC Album Query: 347 Artist
> Query 275

Here is the db I use:
[SQLite Sample Database](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

It prints only first album with first artist. I added integers to see how many times loops run and that's where the problem. There is 347 album and it does goes to 375 but there is 275 artist. When I add a variable to count "for x in artist" I saw that it only  275 times it loops but it should be 347*275, I guess. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the output of your data as well, i.e. artist and album? You might have to change your for loop, I'll be able to help once I can see the data snippet.

Comment: `When I add a variable to count`: Where is that variable in your code and where do you increment it?

Comment: `code` import sqlite3
co=sqlite3.connect("chinook.db")
album=co.execute("select*from albums")
artist=co.execute("select*from artists")
albumQuery=0
artistQuery=0
for row in album:
    albumQuery+=1
    for x in artist:
        artistQuery+=1
        if(x[0]==row[2]):
            print(row[1]+" "+x[1])

print("Album Query:",albumQuery,"Artist Query",artistQuery)`code`

Comment: I'd like to see the data you fetch from sqlite, not the output of your code per se

Comment: Well it is just chinook sample database if you have time to look : https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: Try to remove the if condition and see if all the rows are printed.  If yes, then print the values for x[0] and row[2] and check if they’re equal or not?.

Comment: Additionally, if they’re string then strip off the extra spaces, and typecast if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`co.execute` returns a generator. All its content is used after the first iteration of the outer loop. Extract all contents from the generator into a list *before* starting the loop and iterate over the list:

```
artist = list(co.execute("select*from artists"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, as per @DYZ said:

```
import sqlite3

co=sqlite3.connect("chinook.db")
album = list(co.execute("select*from albums"))
artist = list(co.execute("select*from artists"))
albumQuery=0
artistQuery=0

for row in album:
    albumQuery+=1
    for x in artist:
        artistQuery+=1
        if (int(x[0]) == int(row[2])):
            print(row[1]+" "+x[1])
# print("Album Query:",albumQuery,"Artist Query",artistQuery)
```

Comment: No need to convert `album` to a list.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like `select*from albums` return just one item.